How to make C# work with Google Calendar Api V3
Problem Description:
While integrating the Google Calendar API with a C# application, I encountered an Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch issue during the OAuth 2.0 authentication process. This error suggests that the redirect URI used in the application does not match the one registered in the Google API Console.
Steps leading to the problem:

Attempted to authenticate the application using OAuth 2.0.
Received an error screen stating, "Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid," with additional details about the redirect URI mismatch.

I need guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully authenticate the C# application with the Google Calendar API.
I was trying to create an event in Google Calendar via its Api. I tried the steps provided in google console, but nothing works as I am getting this error of OAuth 2 error code. Error code provided by OAuth 2.0
Error message:
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
You can't sign in this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.
I already registered all uri and all but the thing seems to not get the data.

This question is similar to: Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
